# If the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin 3x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2}+b}$ exists and equals $0$ then what can $a$ and $b$ be?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry, indeterminate-forms

Let $$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin 3x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2}+b}=0$$
given that $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and are finite.

I tried the following approach,

We know, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}}=1$

$$\therefore L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}\cdot \frac{3}{x^2}+\frac{a}{x^2}+b}$$

substituting $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}}=1$

$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{3}{x^2}}+\frac{a}{x^2}+b$$

after some simplification
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{bx^2+a+3}{x^2}}$$

Now, for L to exist $bx^2+a+3 \to 0$
Hence, $$\boxed{a=-3}$$

and as $$L=0 \implies \boxed{b=0}$$ but this is wrong! $b \not= 0$

I tried to plot $f(x)=\frac{\sin 3x}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x^2}$ (image attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlzgU.png)). Clearly from graph $b=\frac{9}{2}$. But what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: And what if for any $a,b$ this limit does not exist?

Comment: Can you elaborate @zkutch

Comment: After some closer inspection using Taylor expansion I found the correct b, but I still don't get why this approach leads to a wrong solution.

Comment: I meant that starting the sentence with "if" you can work with a non-existent object. Even if, using assumption, you have successfully completed the work you must go back and first prove that such a limit exists.

Comment: Do you mean that we must first prove (or disprove) that the limit L exists for some a and b in real number set, and then depending on the result, procced to find a and b (if we have successfully proved that L exists for some real a and b), or the other way around @zkutch

Comment: Yes, you exactly formulated it. The use of Taylor's formula saves you from having to start the sentence with "if".

Comment: Can we prove it by epsilon-delta definition of limits? (I'm in calculus 1 right now I don't know too much about proving limits) @zkutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sum, you cannot apply $\sin(x)\approx x$.

The correct approach would be first looking for a common denominator: $$\dfrac{bx^3+ax+\sin(3x)}{x^3}$$

By Taylor's Theorem, we know $$\sin(3x)=3x-\dfrac{27}{6}x^3+g(x)x^4=3x-\dfrac{9}{2}x^3+g(x)x^4$$

for some function $g$ such that $g(x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0$.

Thus, the expression transforms to $$\dfrac{(b-9/2)x^3+(a+3)x+g(x)x^4}{x^3}$$

For its limit to exist we need $$a+3=0\iff \boxed{a=-3}$$

And we will have $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{bx^3+ax+\sin(3x)}{x^3}=b-\dfrac{9}{2}$$ for any $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, we will need $b=\dfrac{9}{2}$ for $L$ to be $0$.

Comment: Can't we find a and b without using Taylor expansion?

Comment: Applying L'Hôpital's Rule, for example

Comment: Please read my latest comment on this question @Julio Puerta

Comment: @Jesko It is true $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(3x)}{x^3}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\cdot \dfrac{3}{x^2}=+\infty$, but you may not use this in a sum. For instance, using $\sin(x)\approx x $ in $\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$ would lead to thinking the limit is $0$, while it is actually $-1/3$, as can be seen using Taylor expansion or L'Hôpital.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just "substitute" $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} = 1$. A proper way of doing it is using Landau notation, i.e.,
$$\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} = 1 - \frac{3}{2}x^2 + O(x^4).$$
Then you get
$$L = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{bx^2+a+3(1 - \frac{3}{2}x^2 + O(x^4))}{x^2} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{bx^2+a+3 - \frac{9}{2}x^2 + O(x^4)}{x^2}.$$
Therefore you need to put $a = -3$ and $b = \frac{9}{2}$.

Comment: Why can't I substitute it? @klaus and isn't there any other way than using Laudau Notation?

Comment: @Jesko That's just not how limits work. Consider $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}$. Then if you substitute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x = 0$, you get $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x} = 0$, which is nonsense.

Comment: I heard from someone that "we can substitute any thing which is finite and non zero", so is this statement false?

Comment: @Jesko Well, you did exactly that and got a wrong result. What is your conclusion?

Comment: Yeah, It is not a general result. I must not repeat that same mistake.

Comment: @Jesko $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{sin(3x)}{x^3} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{sin (3x)}{(3x)} \frac{3}{x^2}$$ Here you see that $\frac{3}{x^2}$ results in the limit to be $∞$. What you learnt is absolutely correct, you can infact substitute any non zero finite value in the denominator, but it's not useful here. Here you're bound to use Taylor series or Landau notation

Comment: @Gwen Then please explain me why this substitution outputs an absurd result?

Comment: @Jesko I just did. That extra $\frac{3}{x^2}$ you get makes the value of the limit to be $\infty$